# balanced file distribution structure

Tags: php, file, file-upload, directory

I have a server where archived files will be uploaded and stored.  In order to improve performance of listing and checking file existance, I need to organzie the files in performance oriented directory structure.

I have a database table that will hold the real name of the files and their temp name.

```
###################################
FILES
###################################
id int auto_increment primary key,
name varchar (255),
temp_name varchar (255)
```

The root directory can contain a max of 1000 subdrectories ranging from 0-999. Each of the directories will hold 1000 files.

So the result will be

```
root/0 ==> will hold file having the id range from 1-999
root/1 ==> will hold file having the id range from 1000-1999
root/2 ==> will hold file having the id range from 2000-1999
.
.
.
root/999 ==> will hold file having the id range from 999,000-999,999
```

the directory where a file is stored can be found using the following equation

```
$directory = floor($file_id_from_db/1000);
```

WHERE $file_id_from_db is retrived from the files database table `files`.`id`.

The problem takes place when 1,000,000th file is uplaoded then I have to start storing the files in a second level.

I have to create a second level of directories ranging from 0 - 999 in the 0th directory
root/0/0 - root/0/999

then when I reach root/0/999 and I have placed 1000 files in it I need to move to 
root/1/999 and so on till I reach root/999/999.

my current function looks something like that

```
function getPath($id){    
     $result = floor($file_id/1000);
     //Second level checks (Tried and crashed and burned)
     return "/$result"; 
}
```

**I have no idea how to implement the logic for creating the subdirectories?**

Thank for any suggestions.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement the logic for creating the subdirectories?

Comment: Check out the last update. I think I finally got what you want to do.

Comment: Putting a question mark on a statement still does not a question make. Apparently you would benefit more from a tutorial than from an answer, so I would say you're not asking on the right site, even though you did get answers.

Comment: No Mr. grammer police, I did not get an answer. I got alternative solutions none of which solved my problem if you had read though what I have written you would not have asked "what's the question". Don't be mean, I had a question, I checked the answers and although they are all alternative solutions I still have given them a thumbs up. If you don't like a post don't be hater, hater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If another approach is possible you can try the following:

- pad the db-id to e.g. 20 places (something that will suffice for the long run) like: `00000000000001665765`
- split that string into chunks of suitalbe lenghts (e.g. 2) and rejoin those with your DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

This will then be your storage path, e.g.:

```
$id = 1665765;
$paddedId = str_pad($id, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo $path = '/' . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, str_split($paddedId, 2));

// ==> /00/00/00/00/00/00/01/66/57/65
```

this way, you'll have at most 100 directories/files per directory. (this will of course be different if you choose another *split-length*)

To easily create the directory you can use the third parameter for [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/function.mkdir.php).

```
mkdir(dirname($path), 0755, true);
```

Comment: I was thinking about your solution and here's what I don't get? assuming that you want to create 4 levels structure. your code fills only the last level directories with files. the upper levels are always empty.

Comment: For example file 111999 will give \000\000\000\111\999 so it's stored in the 111 directory which located in the 4th level.

Comment: Same for file 0, its saved in \000\000\000\000\000 which is located in level 4.

Comment: @THE_OS Yes that is correct. But I wouldn't see this as a problem. The aim was to reduce the number of subdirectories/files per directory. This is accomplished. Also you're freed from *looking for a file*, as the storage path is directly derivable from the database id.

Comment: I was trying to implement it as a tree. When the first level is completly filled the next level is used. I will try to implemnt this and see. If I don't manage then I will take yours as its the best answer I have recieved till now

Comment: @THE_OS To be honest, why even bother with the tree? Who cares if a directory is *filled*. I'd say that's just a very human way of looking at it. ;)  Your program will see no benefit in filled directories.

Comment: Not my decision, it comes from above. I was kinda lazy and did not feel like writing an algorithm this morning so I posted the question but now I have to write any way.

Comment: Gotta mark you as an correct answer as yours was the closest to what I wanted. I have witten an algorithm that creates the tree thou.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and works like a charm.

```
$dir = str_pad(substr( ($file_id + 1000), 0, (strlen(($file_id + 1000)) - 3)), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

All folders have 5 digits like this: 00001

That way it will ensure 2 comes after 1 not 10 and so on.

Simple and effective.

**Addition:** if you want to start from 0 not one use it like this. (Note the -1)

```
$dir = str_pad(substr( ($file_id + 1000), 0, (strlen(($file_id + 1000)) - 3)) - 1, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Another addition:** I think i got what you want to fo.

Try this: It will add sub-folders in the existing folders once you reach 1 million.

```
$dir = str_pad(substr( ($file_id + 1000), 0, (strlen(($file_id + 1000)) - 3)) - 1, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
if($dir > 1000) { $dir = str_pad(substr($dir, 0, strlen($dir) - 3), 4, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_pad(substr($dir, -3) - 1, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always shuffle the files between the same 10 directories, numbered from 00001 to 00009? I tested with `echo '<?php for ($file_id = 0; $file_id < 1000000; $file_id++) print str_pad(substr( ( $file_id + 1000 ), 0, 1), 5, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n"; ?>' | php -q | sort | uniq`

Comment: It does not work since a file having the id of 1,000,000 should be placed in a subdirectory

Comment: @THE_OS File ID 1 million goes in directory 01001 - Try it

Comment: Yet but I don't want to have 1001 directories in the root directory.

Comment: Please read the description. I want a tree like structure that fills level by level. I am writing the algorith at the moment. I need to reduce the number of files per directory to 1000 in order to improve performance.

Comment: Well you actually have just 1000 as the first the counter starts from 1 not 0. so 01001 is the 1000th folder.

Comment: Ok I think I got what you want to do. Check out the last sample of code I placed just now.

Comment: I have just tried your solution and tried it with $file_id = 90000000; Which results in 9000\00-1. I believe that you have not understood what I really wanted I wanted. I wanted files to be placed level by level starting from the first level and going down the tree.

Comment: Make a folder structure on your pc and take a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

May this function suits you better ?

```
function getPath($id)
{
    if ($id < 100) return "0".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $id = str_pad($id,strlen($id)+(3-strlen($id)%3),"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $in = array_map(create_function('$x','return ($x >= 1) ? ltrim($x,\'0\') : "0";'),str_split($id,3));
    array_pop($in);
    $in = array_reverse($in);
    return rtrim(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$in),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
```

Test pad : http://codepad.org/alRDCWlU

Comment: echo getPath(3000000000); returns \\3\

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you need to hash (or otherwise elaborate) an integer (`id`) so that it can be evenly spread on a target address space.

One way is the one you're adopting. Say that you want to hold at most one thousand billion records, therefore the maximum number you manage is 999,999,999,999 or four levels.

```
function storeFile($id, $source_path)
{
    GLOBAL $BASE_PATH;
    $seq = sprintf("%012d", $id); // Transforms 42 in 000000000042

    $dir = str_split($seq, 3);  // Transforms in { 000 000 000 042 }

    $file = array_pop($dir);    // Get 042 which is the file name
```

Upon creation, **we need to create intermediate directories if needed** (**EDIT**: actually @Yoshi's solution is much better)

```
    // Now build directory

    $path = $BASE_PATH;
    foreach($dir as $component)
    {
        $path .= "/$component";
        if (!is_dir($path))
            mkdir($path);
    }
    // The above can be replaced with mkdir(getPath($id), 0755, true); [@Yoshi]

    // Now $path exists and is /my/base/path/000/000/000

    // $path/$file is my file name, 042 in $path
    rename($source_path, $dest_path = "$path/$file");

    // Just to check. TRUE if everything was hunky dory; FALSE if something went bad.
    return file_exists($dest_path);
```

}

Every time you **store** a file, you run the above and create the directory if needed.

On recovery, you can just run

```
  function getPath($id)
  {
      GLOBAL $BASE_PATH;
      return $BASE_PATH . implode('/', str_split(sprintf("%012d", $id), 3));
  }
```

and directly get the filename.

**UPDATE**: '/' is Unix path separator (should work under Windows too), but you may want to replace it with your platform's directory separator.

If you want to keep the file name (not always advisable since it is under the user's control, international characters might clash with file system encoding, and so on), you can do it like this. We now only need three levels, so a 3*3 path:

```
function storeFile($id, $source_path)
{
    GLOBAL $BASE_PATH;
    $seq = sprintf("%09d", $id); // Transforms 42 in 00000042

    $dir = str_split($seq, 3);  // Transforms in { 000 000 042 }

    // Now build directory. 042 is last directory

    $path = $BASE_PATH;
    foreach($dir as $component)
    {
        $path .= "/$component";
        if (!is_dir($path))
            mkdir($path);
    }

    // Use name component of source file
    $file = basename($source_path);

    // $path/$file is my file name, 042 in $path
    rename($source_path, $dest_path = "$path/$file");

    // Just to check. TRUE if everything was hunky dory; FALSE if something went bad.
    return file_exists($dest_path);
}
```

`getPath` stays the same, except that it will now require `09d` instead of `012d`. If you want to limit to two levels of size 3, reduce further to `06d`.